# How to define a Type A in Type B and Type B in Type A?

Tags: c, delphi, pointers, types, record

I have two types. One Type A and one Type B. The Problem Type A contains Type B and Type B contains Type A. Such a thing like this won't work:

```
  type
    typeA = record
       test1 : typeB;
    end;
  type
    typeB = record
       test2 : typeA;
    end;
```

**Edit:**
Thats not my design. I converting C Header files (to access a DLL)  that include such constructs to delphi.

**Edit2:** 
"C++ structs are another name for classes AFAIR. And there must have been pointers, not values themselves. – Arioch 'The 1 min ago"
Yes you are right that was a Pointer to a Type:

There I definied:

```
test1 : ^typeB;
```

Will that work instead?

```
test1 : Pointer;
```

**Edit3:**
The C Structs:

```
/* DLPDFPAGE */
typedef struct dlpdfpage
{
    CosObj              Page;
    CosObj      PrintSelect;
    ASFixedRect         PageBBox;
    ASFixedRect         ContentBBox;
    struct dlpdfpage    *Next;
    PDRotate            Angle;
    struct dlpdfdoc     *Doc;
    DLPDFSTREAM         *Content;
    long                PageNumber;
    char                Complete;
    char                FontSubstituted;
    char                FontMM;
    char                FontBad;
} DLPDFPAGE;


/* DLPDFDOC */
typedef struct dlpdfdoc
{
    DLPDFINSTANCE       *dliInstance;
    PDDoc               pdDoc;
    CosDoc              cosDoc;
    DLPDFOUTLINE        *Outlines;
    char                *PDFFileName;
    char                *PDFPostFileName;
    DLPOS               LastPageEnd;
    DLPOS               BeforeDef;
    ASFixedRect         DocBBox;
    long                PageCount;
    long                PageTreeWidth;
    long                PageTreeDepth;
    long                PageTreeDepthUsed;
    DLPDFPAGETREEARRAY  *AllPages;
    DLPDFFONTLIST       *AllFonts;
    DLPDFFORMLIST       *AllForms;
    DLPDFFORMLIST       *AllColors;
    DLPDFIMAGELIST      *AllImages;
    DLPDFSPOTCOLORLIST  *AllSpotColors;
    DLPDFSPOTCOLORLIST  *AllPatterns;
    DLPDFEXTGSTATELIST  *AllExtGStates;
    DLPDFPAGE           *PageList;
    DLPDFPAGE           *LastPage;
    DLPDFDEST           *DeferedDests;
    DLPDFSIGNATURE      *signatureHolder;
    struct dlpdfacroform *AcroFormBase;
    CosObj              PatternColorObj,
                        PatternColorRGBObj,
                        PatternColorCMYKObj,
                        PatternColorGrayObj,
            PrintSelect,
            PrintSelectCriteria;
    CosObj      IdentH, IdentV;
    ASAtom              DocumentEncoding;
    long                FontCount;
    long                FormCount;
    long                PatCount;
    long                ImageCount;
    char                Compress;
    char                Linearize;
    char                PageTreeComplete;
    char                EmbedFonts;
    char                PatternColorsDefined;
    char                MakeThumbNails;
    ASBool              psSevenBitSafe;
    ASInt32             EncryptKeyByteCount;

    char                condenseResDicts;
    CosObj              resourceDict;  

    ASInt16             pdfMajorVer;    
    ASInt16             pdfMinorVer;    

    DLPDFINCLUDEDRES    *InclRes;       

    DLPDFSPOTCOLORLIST  *AllShadings;
    long                ShadeCount;

} DLPDFDOC;
```

Comment: C++ structs are another name for classes AFAIR. And there must have been pointers, not values themselves.

Comment: You should post the original C type declaration so we can offer some actual help, beyond explaining why what you tried doesn't work.

Comment: @Arioch'The, even if the `C++` struct would be the same as `class`, a C++ class is not automatically allocated from the heap and a variable of the class type would not automatically be a reference type (unlike in Delphi). This is not a pointer in C++: `aname aClassType;` - but this is: `aname* aClassType;`.

Comment: i posted the C Sruct parts

Comment: Q.E.D. - asterisk "*" in C means pointer, like "^" caret in PAscal

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You misunderstood what those C structs represent. That's because a `record` is a value type: it's stored right there where you declare the variable. So let's do a few levels of recursive declarations, and you'll understand what I mean; Assuming the two structures aren't absolutely identical:

```
type
  TA = record
     test1 : TB;
     SomethingElseFromA: Byte;
  end;

  TB = record
     test2 : TA;
     SomethingElseFromB: Byte;
  end;
```

Structure `TA` could be rewritten to mean this:

```
type
  TA = record
    // Replaced test1 : TB with the actual content of TB, because that's
    // what a record means.
    test1_test2: TA;
    test1_SomethingElseFromB: Byte;

    SomethingElseFromA: Byte;
  end;
```

Of course, we've now got a nice recursive inclusion of self into the `TA` record, something along the lines of:

```
  TA = record
    // Replaces test1_test: TA
    test1_test2: TA; // Oops, still not fixed, need to do it again...
    test1_SomethingElseFromB: Byte;
    SomethingElseFromA: Byte;

    test1_SomethingElseFromB: Byte;
    SomethingElseFromA: Byte;
  end;
```

You probably want to use reference types to get something that looks similar, but it's not similar. A reference type is always a pointer, so it's a fixed size; The compiler can allocate it without a problem. This would be valid, using pointers-to-records:

```
type
  pTypeB = ^typeB;
  pTypeA = ^typeA;

  typeA = record
     test1 : pTypeB;
  end;

  typeB = record
     test2 : pTypeA;
  end;
```

Alternatively you could use classes; That works for the same reason, classes are reference types; they work the same way as pointers. When you declare a variable of pointer-type, the compiler allocates `SizeOf(Pointer)` bytes.

---

Since you've posted the C structs, I can tell they're too long for me to attempt a complete translation, but I can make a few suggestions: You should declare all your types in a single `Type` block; don't write the `Type` before each type declaration. This allows you to create the pointer type before the record type, like this:

```
Type
  PMyRecord = ^TMyRecord;

  // Somewhere in the same Type block
  TMyRecord = record
  end;
```

For each type that requires pointers-to-records, declare the pointers first thing after the `Type` keyword, it's simpler that way. Next, you need to identify the C pointers. If there's a `*` between the name of the data type and the name of the field, that's a pointer. This is usually written like this:

```
int *PointerToSomeInt;
```

But those would be just as valid:

```
int * PointerToSomeInt;
int* VarName1, * VarName1, * VarName3; // Three pointers to integer.
```

Finally, you'll need to deal with alignment issues. If you can, check the size of the structures on the C side, and then check the size on the Delphi side: you should get the same size. If you don't, you should try a couple of random `{$ALIGN}` compiler directives before your structure declaration and repeat until you strike the correct alignment. If all else fails you'll need to find what's wrong (what fields are aligned differently on the Delphi side) and put in some alignment bytes to artificially fix it.

Comment: @frugi, if this is required for importing a `C`-written DLL, it's not all about compiling, it's about getting a Pascal data structure that represents the exact same data, in the exact same layout. It will not work any other way. Please post the original `C` structures, because we can't really help if we only see the pascal side of it.

Comment: Okay thanks i got it working with your type
  pTypeB = ^typeB;
  pTypeA = ^typeA;
... solution. +1 that was very nice :)

Comment: Especially that is an important: "You should declare all your types in a single Type block, don't write the Type before each type declaration."

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps the best solution is to rethink the design. But you might also be interested in so-called *forward declarations* of classes:

```
type
  TTypeB = class;

  TTypeA = class
    test: TTypeB;
  end;

  TTypeB = class
    test: TTypeA;
  end;
```

SIC! This only works for classes, not records.

Comment: Ah, didn't have Delphi to test on here so didn't know of the record/class restriction. +1 for you. It makes sense though, putting a value type inside a value type inside a value type... can't really work very well :)

Comment: BTW, Andreas, can this be done for interfaces ? I know, i can just put IInterface reference and do dynamic casting, but i mean exactly trick like this to get compile-time type checking.

Comment: It probably could be variant record, in 1974 Pascal sense

Comment: @Arioch'The: Not sure, but I'd bet David knows.

Comment: [David Heffernan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan), our own Delphi legend.

Comment: Yes, @Arioch, classes and interfaces can both have forward declarations. Cosmin's answer demonstrates *pointer* forward declarations. I'm not sure what you think variant records (in both the 1974 Pascal sense and the 2013 Delphi sense, since they're the same) would add to this topic.

Comment: See Andreas's example here, @Arioch, but say `interface` instead of `class`.

Comment: Maybe you could post a question about it on Stack Overflow, @Arioch. "How do I write a forward declaration for interfaces?"

Answer (score 1):

The Delphi translation of the C code you showed would look like this:

```
type
  DLPDFDOC = record; // forward declaration

  { DLPDFPAGE }
  DLPDFPAGE = record
    Page: CosObj;
    PrintSelect: CosObj;
    PageBBox: ASFixedRect;
    ContentBBox: ASFixedRect;
    Next: ^DLPDFPAGE;
    Angle: PDRotate;
    Doc: ^DLPDFDOC;
    Content: ^DLPDFSTREAM;
    PageNumber: Longint;
    Complete: AnsiChar;
    FontSubstituted: AnsiChar;
    FontMM: AnsiChar;
    FontBad: AnsiChar;
  end;

  { DLPDFDOC }
  DLPDFDOC = record
    dliInstance: ^DLPDFINSTANCE;
    pdDoc: PDDoc;
    cosDoc: CosDoc;
    Outlines: ^DLPDFOUTLINE;
    PDFFileName: PAnsiChar;
    PDFPostFileName: PAnsiChar;
    LastPageEnd: DLPOS;
    BeforeDef: DLPOS;
    DocBBox: ASFixedRect;
    PageCount: Longint;
    PageTreeWidth: Longint;
    PageTreeDepth: Longint;
    PageTreeDepthUsed: Longint;
    AllPages: ^DLPDFPAGETREEARRAY;
    AllFonts: ^DLPDFFONTLIST;
    AllForms: ^DLPDFFORMLIST;
    AllColors: ^DLPDFFORMLIST;
    AllImages: ^DLPDFIMAGELIST;
    AllSpotColors: ^DLPDFSPOTCOLORLIST;
    AllPatterns: ^DLPDFSPOTCOLORLIST;
    AllExtGStates: ^DLPDFEXTGSTATELIST;
    PageList: ^DLPDFPAGE;
    LastPage: ^DLPDFPAGE;
    DeferedDests: ^DLPDFDEST;
    signatureHolder: ^DLPDFSIGNATURE;
    AcroFormBase: ^DLPDFACROFORM;
    PatternColorObj: CosObj;
    PatternColorRGBObj: CosObj;
    PatternColorCMYKObj: CosObj;
    PatternColorGrayObj: CosObj;
    PrintSelect: CosObj;
    PrintSelectCriteria: CosObj;
    IdentH: CosObj;
    IdentV: CosObj;
    DocumentEncoding: ASAtom;
    FontCount: Longint;
    FormCount: Longint;
    PatCount: Longint;
    ImageCount: Longint;
    Compress: AnsiChar;
    Linearize: AnsiChar;
    PageTreeComplete: AnsiChar;
    EmbedFonts: AnsiChar;
    PatternColorsDefined: AnsiChar;
    MakeThumbNails: AnsiChar;
    psSevenBitSafe: ASBool;
    EncryptKeyByteCount: ASInt32;
    condenseResDicts: AnsiChar;
    resourceDict: CosObj;  
    pdfMajorVer: ASInt16;    
    pdfMinorVer: ASInt16;    
    InclRes: ^DLPDFINCLUDEDRES;       
    AllShadings: ^DLPDFSPOTCOLORLIST;
    ShadeCount: Longint;
  end;
```